# Remove-if-not in Racket

Tags: common-lisp, racket, remove-if

In Common Lisp there is a famous built-in function called remove-if-not.

I could not find this on Racket`s documentation.

Did I miss something? Does Racket offer this function with a different name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is available in Racket under the much more standard name, [`filter`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29). Its inverse, the equivalent of CL’s `remove-if`, is available as [`filter-not`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._filter-not%29%29).